# Describing the rotation speed of an automatic pizza saucer

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have an automatic pizza saucer ([as pictured here](http://bowmandickson.com/category/teaching/calculus) ) and want to describe the rotation speed of the saucer by using a simple formula. Do you have an idea how to do that, if the arm and the sauce remain constant in their associated values (thus to say velocity of the arm and output of the sauce remain constant)?

Answer (score 1):

If the saucer arm produces a stripe of sauce whose width is $d$, and move toward the center with constant speed $v$, then when the disc make a $2\pi$ round, the arm should move of a distance $d$, so
$$
d=v\tau \\
2\pi = \omega\tau
$$
from which the angular speed of the disk should be
$$
\omega=2\pi v/d
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now a question for my understanding. We suppose that we have a uniform circular motion. According to that we get as result the velocity of a point on the pizza as product of $\omega$ and r which is the distance to the center of the pizza (radius). So results $v=|\omega|r$, right?

Comment: @Rico1990: yes, but it is not to be confused with the speed of the arm, that I named with your same letter $v$.

Comment: Thank you so far. Now I reflected on the meaning of the integral of that function. Let's call her $v^
*=|\omega|r$
. The result is in my eyes $V^
*=|\omega|rx$
where r is a fixed value depending on my chosen point
. Is it right to say that this function $V^*$ describes the relation of way and time for a chosen point
p?